# Cloud function executes with status OK but data does not write to firestore

Tags: json, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get my firebase cloud function to fetch some JSON and write it to firestore. The function runs, but it doesn't seem to write anything and I can't seem to log if anything is actually getting fetched? Any ideas why it's not fetching and writing to firestore?

When I `console.log(response.data.response.feedMessageResponse.messages.message)`

it shows me the json values I'd expect to see, lat, lng, time etc.

If I try to do console.log(message.messageType) I get nothing.

[image]

Why isn't it being written to firestore?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';

type SpotResponse = {
  response: {
    feedMessageResponse: {
      count: number,
      messages: {
        message: Array<{
          latitude: number,
          longitude: number,
          unixTime: number,
          messageType: string,
          batteryState: string,
        }>,
      },
    },
    errors: Array<{}>,
  },
}

export default async () => {
  const FirestoreInstance = firestore();
    const feedID = '0u88e3hrgRoCDA4JEqkg41U1jhO25PbvW';
    const url = `https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/${feedID}/latest.json`;
    const response = await axios.get<SpotResponse>(url)
    const messages = response.data.response.feedMessageResponse.messages.message;
    console.log(messages);
    while (messages.length > 0) {
      const message = messages.shift();
      if (!message) throw new Error('No more items in the queue');

      const formatedMessage: any = {
        timestamp: firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(message.unixTime * 1000),
        location: new firestore.GeoPoint(message.latitude, message.longitude),
        messageType: message.messageType,
        batteryState: message.batteryState,
      }
      Object.keys(formatedMessage).forEach(key => formatedMessage[key] === undefined && delete formatedMessage[key]);

      FirestoreInstance.collection('locationHistory').doc().create(formatedMessage)
        .then((value: firestore.WriteResult) => {
          console.log('Successfully inserted document', formatedMessage, 'at', value.writeTime);
        })
        .catch((reason: any) => {
          console.error('Could not insert document', reason);
        });
    }
  }
```

This is my index.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import retrievePositionData from './retrievePositionData';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

export const fetchLocations = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('*/10 * * * *')
  .timeZone('America/Montreal')
  .onRun(retrievePositionData);
```

Comment: Fair enough. Question then, how do I verify if I can fetch the data? The url is valid JSON, what am I missing then?

Comment: "I can't seem to log if anything is actually getting fetched" If you `console.log(response)`, what does it output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I tried this earlier and it prints out pages of information, I took a screenshot of the top bit, https://rideyrbike.com/screenshot.png

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The response through postman shows the short JSON file, it's very small, but then console.log in google cloud is ridiculously verbose and I can't seem to copy it all out. Something is out of whack and I'm used to Flutter, not typescript so I'm struggling.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay I changed it to console.log(response.data.response.feedMessageResponse.messages.message) and I see my data exactly as I would expect to see it, thus confirming my data is coming in just fine, so where is the break down that it won't write to firestore?

Comment: Figuring out exactly what line of your code is failing should be your next step. I honestly recommend starting with a local Node.js script and running that (or using the Firebase emulators, although that's more involved). That also then allows you to use a debugger, set breakpoints, and step through the code to see exactly which line is failing. --- Either way it probably helps to show the `console.log` you did, and its output to your question so that we can see it too. But locally debugging is a much faster way to make progress, once you get the hang of the tools.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay I understand how debugging would be easier than what I am trying to do and I appreciate the direction, one last shot I finally have a screen shot of console.log(messages) linked here https://rideyrbike.com/screenshot2.png  You'll see I'm getting Latitude, Longitude, messageType, batteryState Meanwhile I will try getting local node running.

Comment: Are you using `setDoc`? why don't you add that line of code in the question? Show what object/JSON you are passing too.

Comment: @RonnieRoystonn To my knowledge I'm not using setDoc, I added my index.ts file to the question if that helps. And then I'm not quite following on what I need to show. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler way to do it, works well.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';


type SpotResponse = {
  response: {
    feedMessageResponse: {
      count: number,
      messages: {
        message: Array<{
          latitude: number,
          longitude: number,
          unixTime: number,
          messageType: string,
          batteryState: string,
        }>,
      },
    },
    errors: Array<{}>,
  },
}

export default async () => {
  const FirestoreInstance = firestore();
  const feedID = '0u88e3hrgRoCDA4JEqkg41U1jhO25PbvW';
  const url = `https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/${feedID}/latest.json`;
  const response = await axios.get<SpotResponse>(url)
  const messages = response.data.response.feedMessageResponse.messages.message;

  type ObjectKey = keyof typeof messages;
  const myVar = 'latitude' as ObjectKey;

  type ObjectKey2 = keyof typeof messages;
  const myVar2 = 'longitude' as ObjectKey2;

  type ObjectKey3 = keyof typeof messages;
  const myVar3 = 'altitude' as ObjectKey3;

  type ObjectKey4 = keyof typeof messages;
  const myVar4 = 'unixTime' as ObjectKey4;

  const cityRef = FirestoreInstance.collection('2023WNS').doc('uDIP3FvGg2bxDbBusJ9cq4iIyec2');

const res = await cityRef.update({Lat: messages[myVar], Lng: messages[myVar2], Altitude: messages[myVar3], unixtime: messages[myVar4]});
console.log(res);

}
```